# Merge multiple arrays to one array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, array-merge

I am trying to merge my multiple arrays to one array using jquery. I know that we can merge two arrays to one using jquery merge function. And we can loop through those arrays and join them to one too. But I just wanted to know whether there is any other way to achieve this without using any loop. I am handling large number of datas. So I can expect any number of arrays too. I am worrying if we use a loop, it may affect the performance. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Kindest Regards
Sibeesh Venu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `.concat`

and to apply it for multiple array like below

```
var multipleArrays = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

var flatArray = [].concat.apply([], multipleArrays); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

// Using the Spread syntax
var flatArray2 = Array.prototype.concat(...multipleArrays);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: no sense use .concat.apply -- concat return new array itself

Comment: if OP has dynamic number of arrays, use `cocnat.apply` would be easier

Comment: I will try this method and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`array1.concat(array2)` in plain javascript

Comment: As I said in the question, I need to merge so many arrays. Not just two. I have tried this method. Thank you

Comment: just chain the function then: `array1.concat(array2).concat(array3)`

Answer (score 2):

You can just [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) all values from one to another

```
var a = [1,2,3]
var b = [2,3,4,5]
a.push.apply(a, b)
console.log(a);// [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```