# how to merge three arrays and join them with ':'

Tags: javascript, merge, concatenation

```
var a = ["a","b"];
var b = ["c","d"];
var c = ["e","f"];
```

So these are the three arrays. I want the output as:
var d = [a-b:c-d:e-f];

How can it be acheived either using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32066127/4034148

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple arrays to one array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066001/merge-multiple-arrays-to-one-array-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a map and joins

```
var d = [ a, b, c ].map(sub => sub.join("-")).join(":");
```

The first map takes every subarray and joins them (d is `["a-b", "c-d", "e-f"]`), then the last join creates a string out of them by joining the strings using colons.